# layout with 100% height and header/footer

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

In bootstrap 4.5 app I make layout with 100% height and header/footer, based on snippet:

https://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/LmYay/

it works ok, until content part has not too much of data
I tried to add

```
  overflow:auto;
```

definition of .fill-area-content

and added more data:
https://jsfiddle.net/z0o1cmve/1/
but header is not fixed. How can I fix it ?

Thanks!

Comment: do u want to fix both header and footer ? or only header?

Comment: both header and footer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to set the height to  .fill-area-content, header and footer

```
.flexbox-item.header
{
    height:35px;
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .1);
}
.flexbox-item.footer
{
    height:35px;
    background: rgba(0, 255, 0, .1);
}
.fill-area-content
{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    height: calc(100vh - (35px + 35px + 16px) );/* add this */
    overflow: auto; 
}
```

calculation:

35px - height of header
35px - height of footer

Then 8px  padding u have added for `.flexbox-item` on all sides, so on top padding will be 8px and bottom padding will be 8px totally - 16px

hence the formula will `100vh - other elements height` other elements height = (35px + 35px +16px).

So, `height: calc( 100vh - (35px + 35px + 16px ));`.

use `vh-your_custom_height` classname if you are using bootstrap.

```css
*, *:before, *:after
{
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body
{
    background: #444444;
    
    color: #cccccc;
    font-size: 14px;
    /* Helvetica/Arial-based sans serif stack */
    font-family: Frutiger, "Frutiger Linotype", Univers, Calibri, "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", Myriad, "DejaVu Sans Condensed", "Liberation Sans", "Nimbus Sans L", Tahoma, Geneva, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

}

.flexbox-parent
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    
    justify-content: flex-start; /* align items in Main Axis */
    align-items: stretch; /* align items in Cross Axis */
    align-content: stretch; /* Extra space in Cross Axis */
            
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}

.flexbox-item
{
    padding: 8px;
}
.flexbox-item-grow
{
    flex: 1; /* same as flex: 1 1 auto; */
}

.flexbox-item.header
{
    height:35px;
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .1);
}
.flexbox-item.footer
{
    height:35px;
    background: rgba(0, 255, 0, .1);
}
.flexbox-item.content
{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 255, .1);
}

.fill-area
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;    
    justify-content: flex-start; /* align items in Main Axis */
    align-items: stretch; /* align items in Cross Axis */
    align-content: stretch; /* Extra space in Cross Axis */
    
}
.fill-area-content
{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    height: calc(100vh - (35px + 35px + 16px) );
    /* Needed for when the area gets squished too far and there is content that can't be displayed */
    overflow: auto; 
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox-parent">
    <div class="flexbox-item header">
        Header
    </div>
    
    <div class="flexbox-item fill-area content flexbox-item-grow">
        <div class="fill-area-content  flexbox-item-grow">
            Content 
            <br /><br />
            Emulates height 100% with a horizontal flexbox with stretch
            <br /><br />      
            This box with a border should fill the blue area except for the padding (just to show the middle flexbox item).
            
            <p>Lorem <strong>ipsum dolor sit</strong> amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim  veniam, quis <strong>nostrud exercitation</strong> ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea  commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate  velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint  occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt  mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim  veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea  commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate  velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt  mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<ul>
    <li>Lorem 1st point </li>
    <li>Lorem 2nd point </li>
    <li>Lorem 3rd point </li>
</ul>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim  veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea  commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate  velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt  mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>


<p>Lorem <strong>ipsum dolor sit</strong> amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim  veniam, quis <strong>nostrud exercitation</strong> ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea  commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate  velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint  occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt  mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim  veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea  commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate  velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt  mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<ul>
    <li>Lorem 1st point </li>
    <li>Lorem 2nd point </li>
    <li>Lorem 3rd point </li>
</ul>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>, sed do eiusmod  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim  veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea  commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate  velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <i>Excepteur sint  occaecat</i> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt  mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>

        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="flexbox-item footer mb-5 pb-5">
        Footer12
    </div>
</div>
```